# "no suitable constructor exists to convert from "void () to "std::function<void ()>" error when trying to pass a function as argument

Tags: c++

I have an input class that has a method that is supposed to take function as an argument.

```
#include "pixelGameEngine.h"
#include <functional>
class Input
{
public:
    Input() = default;
    Input(const Input&) = delete;
    Input& operator=(const Input&) = delete;

public:
    static void OnDPress(olc::PixelGameEngine* pge, std::function<void()> DoIteration) noexcept
    {
        if (pge->GetKey(olc::D).bPressed)
        {
            DoIteration();
        }
    }
};
```

And I have a triangle processor class that is supposed to call that function.

```
#include "pixelGameEngine.h"
#include "input.h"
#include <functional>
class TriangleProcessor
{
    //...
    void DoIteration() noexcept{};
    Input input;
    void Run(olc::PixelGameEngine* pge)
    {
        Input::OnDPress(pge, DoIteration);
    }
}
```

But I am getting an error `"no suitable constructor exists to convert from "void () to "std::function<void ()>"`on line `Input::OnDPress(pge, DoIteration);` with a red squiggly under `DoIteration`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`DoIteration` is not a function. It's a method defined on the `TriangleProcessor` class. The usual `std::function` constructor you're trying to invoke is for producing `std::function` instances from callable objects or function pointers. `DoIteration` has an implied `this` argument.

Now, you're running this inside of `Run`, which as it happens has access to that implied `this` argument. So, in your case, we likely want to pass on the current `this` value. We can do that

```
Input::OnDPress(pge, [this]() { this->DoIteration(); });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was wondering why you can't do `Input::OnDPress(pge, this->DoIteration});`

Comment: C++ takes the view that, if you're using an abstraction or technique that has a cost, it should be plainly visible. In a language like Python, you can do exactly that: `Input.OnDPress(pge, self.DoIteration)` works flawlessly. But it implicitly creates a closure. A top-level function `DoIteration` is *just* a pointer; it's super cheap to create and pass around. Whereas `[this]() { this->DoIteration(); })` has to create a special object in memory to store the function pointer, the `this` pointer, and the wrapped behavior of the two together. C++ prefers to make such abstractions explicit.